# Initialize cursor style in vim

Tags: vim, zsh

I am curious if there is a method to initialize the cursor style upon entering Vim, preventing it from retaining the style used previously.

In my Vim configuration file `~/.vimrc`, I've included the following settings:

```
if $TERM_PROGRAM =~ "Terminal" 
"Mode settings: 
  let &t_SI.="\e[6 q" "SI = INSERT mode 
  let &t_SR.="\e[2 q" "SR = REPLACE mode 
  let &t_EI.="\e[2 q" "EI = NORMAL mode (ELSE) 
endif
```

In my zsh configuration file `~/.zshrc`, I've implemented the following settings:

```
bindkey -v 

KEYTIMEOUT=1 

function zle-keymap-select { 
  if [[ $KEYMAP == vicmd ]]; then 
    echo -ne "\e[2 q" 
  fi 
  if [[ $KEYMAP == viins ]] || 
     [[ $KEYMAP == main ]]; then 
    echo -ne "\e[6 q" 
  fi 
} 
zle -N zle-keymap-select 

_fix_cursor() { echo -ne '\e[6 q' } 
precmd_functions+=(_fix_cursor)
```

When I open Vim in the terminal using either `vim` or `vim filename`, the cursor maintains the style (solid vertical line) it had before pressing the Enter key. Only after transitioning from insert mode back to normal mode does the cursor style correctly revert to its original appearance (solid block).

Answer (score 1):

As presented by `:help restore-cursor`,

```
augroup RestoreCursor
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ let line = line("'\"")
    \ | if line >= 1 && line <= line("$") && &filetype !~# 'commit'
    \      && index(['xxd', 'gitrebase'], &filetype) == -1
    \ |   execute "normal! g`\""
    \ | endif
augroup END
```

is designed to restore the cursor position upon opening files with the command `vim filename`. Actually it also handles the initialization of the cursor style.

It's worth noting that this behavior doesn't apply when entering Vim using the `vim` command directly. However, there's an additional command:

```
autocmd VimEnter * normal :
```

This command seems to possess the capability to initialize the cursor, regardless of how Vim is entered.